# Error when trying to take the Input from a file path and pass it to an other function using PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, networkx

I'd like to pass the path of a file that I select from my pc

```
def openFileNameDialog(self):
    options = QFileDialog.Options()
    options |= QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog
    fileName, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self,"QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()", "","All Files (*);;Python Files (*.py)", options=options)
    if fileName:
        print(fileName)
```

```
button = QPushButton('Louvain Algorithm', self) button.setToolTip('This is an example button') button.move(50,300) 
button.clicked.connect(self.on_click_louvain)
```

into an other function

```
def on_click_louvain(self,fileName): 
    # Replace this with your networkx graph loading depending on your format !

    G = nx.read_gml(str(fileName,))
```

but i get this error

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'False'

Any ideas for the solution??

Comment: How is `on_click_louvain`  called?

Comment: `button = QPushButton('Louvain Algorithm', self)
        button.setToolTip('This is an example button')
        button.move(50,300)
        button.clicked.connect(self.on_click_louvain) `

This is the button that is pressed and calls the funtction

Comment: `button.clicked.connect(self.on_click_louvain)`: This will call `self.on_click_louvain(checked)` when the button is clicked, where `checked` is a boolean indicating the checked state of the button, not the filename.

Comment: So which is the way to pass the path to the ` G = nx.read_gml(*path*) ` ?

Comment: Probably the easiest way is to store the filename in an instance variable, i.e. in `openFileNameDialog()` set `self.filename=filename` and in `on_click_louvain` use `self.filename` to load the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several misconceptions:

- The variable "fileName" is local, so it cannot be accessed in other methods.
- The variable "fileName" will not be passed magically as an argument of another method. Also by default the clicked signal has a Boolean associated and that is the one that is generating the error.

The solution is to store the variable as an attribute of the class and then access through the object:

```py
def openFileNameDialog(self):
    options = QFileDialog.Options()
    options |= QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog
    fileName, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self,"QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()", "","All Files (*);;Python Files (*.py)", options=options)
    self.fileName = fileName
```

```
def on_click_louvain(self): 
    # Replace this with your networkx graph loading depending on your format !
    G = nx.read_gml(self.fileName)
```

Comment: Yes, it is exactly what I did. Thank you, too!